# Load TypeScript module from string in memory?

Tags: node.js, typescript

```
function requireFromString(src, filename) {
  var Module = module.constructor;
  var m = new Module();
  m._compile(src, filename);
  return m.exports;
}

console.log(requireFromString(`
  const a = require('./a');
  const fs = require('fs');
  module.exports = { test: a}
`));
```

We can require node module by this.

Can we require TypeScript module in memory?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking this: [How to compile TypeScript code in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23076788/6384980)

Or use only typescriptServices.js:

```
     <script src="https://rawgit.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/master/lib/typescriptServices.js"></script>
```

And add js code:

```
   var hello = "test";
   var js = ts.transpile("let a = `<div>${hello}</div>`");
   console.log(js);
   eval(js);
   console.log(a);
```

Where `ts.transpile` translate ts to js string.

[Examle on next.plnkr.co](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/udEdhIsojz0XEjgO).

Comment: I want import some module in runtime? like `import * as foo from 'a.ts'`

Comment: At the output, you will get the necessary javascript but you should control the modules yourself, use [babeljs.io](https://babeljs.io/)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is called dynamic imports. Check out https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2018/01/14/typescript-2-4-dynamic-import-expressions